# EF Include Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Использую ASP Net Core Web API и EF Core. Возникает интересная магия, которую постичь никак не удалось.

Имеется `IEfCotntext`:

```
public interface IEfContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;
    ...
}

public class EfContext : DbContext, IEfContext
{
    ...
    public new DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{

    public DbSet<TEntity> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            return dbset ?? context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }
    ...
    public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Entities;

        if (includes != null)
            foreach (var include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

        if (where != null)
            query = query.Where(where);

        var result = await query.ToListAsync();
        query = result.ToList().AsQueryable();

        return query;
    }
    ...
}
```

Модель Category:

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Через `ICategoryService` пытаюсь получить данные из БД:

```
return await categoryRepository.GetAsync(model => model.ParentId == null, x => x.Children, x => x.Products);
```

У возвращаемых данных у каждого объекта из `Childred`, свойства `Childen` и `Products` равны `null`. Но вот проходя отладчиком

[image: 1]

Именно только когда пытаюсь получить `Results View` данные возвращаются правильно

[image: 2]

Пытался закрывать соединения (`.ToList()`) везде где только можно. Но функция также продолжает некорректно работать.

Comment: Как я понимаю, происходит следующее: через отладчик при раскрытии Results View делается запрос на выбор всех данных + include(), а после фильтруется Where(). Без отладчика с помощью IQueryable собирается запрос, а после отсылается и результатом становится объекты Where() и применённый к ним Include(), т.е. только первый уровень. Поэтому мне нужно делать Include("Children.Children.Children...") либо выгружать все элементы в память, а потом применять Where(). Очень жаль если я прав :(

Comment: @АлександрСанков А может оформите ваш комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Фокус раскрыт:**
Как только происходит обращение к Results View через отладчик, сразу же посылается запрос к БД. В моём случае, `context.Categories.Include(model=>model.Children)` (всё логично, ведь мы хотим увидеть, что происходит на данном этапе).

После этого фильтруются данные с помощью `Where(...)`. И результатом является, та иерархическая структура, которая была нужна.

При вызове без отладки, отправляется запрос `context.Categories.Where(model.ParentId == null).Include(model=>model.Children)`. Т.е. сначала выбираются родительские категории, и к ним применяется INNER JOIN для коллекций Children (соответственно только на первом уровне).

**Поэтому** нужно помнить, что запрос выполняется, как только IQueryable полностью сформирован, а раскрытие Results View при отладке делает дополнительный запрос.

`loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);` в Startup.cs в `Configure(...)` показывает именно этот запрос при раскрытии Results View.

**Иерархическая структура:** Что же касается выгрузки иерархической структуры из БД, то всё гораздо проще. Идея выгрузить из БД *все данные*, которые входят в эту структуру. Т.е. если нужно сформировать *все категории* в виде дерева, нужно выгрузить их *все*:

Делаем запрос из IRepository:

```
var categories = await categoryRepository.GetAsync(); //т.е. все категории
return categories.ToList();
```

Делаем ViewModel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Через AutoMapper все виртуальные свойства заполнятся:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
```

В Controller:

```
var categoriesViewModel = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<ViewModels.Tree.CategoryViewModel>>(categories.Where(model=>model.ParentId == null));
```

И в итоге получаем требуемый результат.

Если нужно получить только одну категорию со всеми дочерними элементами, то соответственно нужно выгрузить эту категорию и все дочерние запросом, но этого уже другой вопрос

Comment: Этот ответ является наиболее полным и исчерпывающим, поставьте на него галку.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скринам, отладчиком вы пользуетесь и просматриваете `Results View` еще до того как контекст EF был разрушен. Соответственно, при раскрытии дерева в отладчике просто срабатывает `LazyLoad` и вы получаете даже те данные, которые не были подключены в `Include`. Если вы выведете все запросы которые делает ваш контекст в окно Output, вы сами увидите доп. запросы:

```
_context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Просматривая же возвращаемые данные, вы уже оперируете 'POCO' объектами, а не прокси-объектами EF, соответственно все навигационные свойства, которые не были явно указаны в Include, будут равны `null`.

Comment: .Database.Log отсутствует в EF Core. Применяем loggerFacroty и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скринам, вы просматриваете `query` до применения предиката. Это вызывает загрузку таблицы целиком и материализацию всех объектов.

Когда материализованный объект уже находится в контексте - он будет записываться в навигационные свойства независимо от инклюдов.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/132282)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov почему вы считаете, что это не является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: Возможно, но мне он кажется совсем неполным, поэтому больше похож на комментарий. Просто подсказать направление по сути. Всё же комментарий @АлександрСанков намного больше бы подошёл потому что у него есть ещё и решение, а не только ответ почему.